# Argument Error - Whitelist and sanitize passed parameters to be secure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-5, sanitization

I just upgraded to Rails 5.0.1, and I'm running into a security warning:

```
ArgumentError in Categories#show
Showing /home/user/website/app/views/categories/show.html.erb where line #127 raised:

Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters! An attacker 
can inject malicious data into the generated URL, such as changing the host. 
Whitelist and sanitize passed parameters to be secure.
```

This is the offending code:

```
<%= link_to "Title", params.merge(:utf8 => params[:utf8], :search => params[:search], :x => "5", :y => ""), title:"Alphabetical" %>
```

I searched for this error and found a few similar problems, but they were either solved my running `permit!` instead of just `permit` (which is inapplicable in my situation) or the problem was a bug, which I hope isn't the case. I tried adding `html_safe` to my parameters but it didn't help.

Anyone know how I can sanitize my parameters to abide by Rails 5 security measures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sanitize `params` as follows

```
<%= link_to "Title",
  params.merge(
    :utf8 => params[:utf8],
    :search => params[:search],
    :x => "5",
    :y => "").permit(:utf8, :search, :x, :y),
  title:"Alphabetical" %>
```